# What does こと before a noun mean?

Tags: grammar

Here are two examples of こと being used in the beginning of a sentence/clause:

> **こと**性愛を司るイシュタルには、ベルの訴えは届かない。
> To Ishutal, who rules over eros, Bell's reasoning was useless. (?)

Context: Ishutal is a goddess of love and beauty in this story. Bell attempts to convince her that forcing someone to prostitute themselves is not moral.

Here is another example:

> ヴェルフならば火を通しただけのいわゆる男料理、リリならば材料をぎりぎりまで抑えた節約料理など、それぞれの性格や調理の腕が食卓に現れるが、**こと**命【みこと】の料理に限ってはファミリアの全ての者から『美味い』と太鼓判を押されている。

What do these こと mean in these sentences? Are they the same こと?

Comment: According to [this Italki post](https://www.italki.com/post/question-466593?hl=ja), It seems to be used to emphasize the following sentence, almost like the adverb 特別に.

Comment: They are the same 殊【こと】 meaning "especially" or "in particular". It indicates the following noun is special among others.

Comment: This こと might be translated like: "Bell's appeal did not reach Ishtar, who, *of all gods*, is the ruler of eros".